# Deleting all objects(files & folders) from an Amazon S3 bucket folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an Amazon S3 bucket[**example-bucket**] and a folder[**prod**] in it, the use case is to delete all the objects[files and folders] of ***prod*** folder.

I tried with this:

aws s3 rm s3://example-bucket/ --recursive --exclude="*" --include="prod/*.*"

it deletes the files but not the folders from /prod folder, which does not solve my problem. I just want to empty this **prod** folder.

I will appreciate the help provided to empty the folder.

thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your description? The first sentence mentions deleting all the objects under the `prod/` prefix*, yet you later mention that deleting the files from the prefix* does not solve your problem. It may help to understand that object storage does not have "folders" - e.g. `prod/example.txt` would be the full name of an object - and `prod/` would be referred to as the object's prefix.

Comment: need to empty prod/ folder, which contains both sub-folders and objects files.

Comment: Try: `aws s3 rm s3://example/bucket/prod/ --recursive`

Comment: For large number of files, it would be the best simply add a lifecycle policy to expire the objects under the `prod/` prefix, both current and previous versions (if your bucket is versioned).

Answer (score 1):

To empty the prod objects on the prod folder, your command will look like this:

```
aws s3 rm s3://example-bucket/prod --recursive
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#empty-bucket